# Is it possible to make Gradle build fail if apk artifacts are not generated for some reason?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, bamboo, artifact

Actually I'm using Gradle with Bamboo for Continuous Deployment and I've noticed that, with an edit I've done, when Bamboo builds my application, it doesn't build the .apk artifacts on Bamboo. Nevertheless, the build is done successfully.

My questions is that I would make the Gradle build fail if artifacts are not generated.

Is it a thing I can make inside the Gradle configuration or is it a thing I have to handle on Bamboo?

Let me know if you need further informations.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it seems like you want to do a hack. Why are the APKs not generated? If you want to generate them in every build configure gradle this way.

Comment: Maybe I haven't described the problem in depth, the APKs are generated by Gradle, but on Bamboo the path where the .apk files are searched have changed and now they're different from the paths specified on Bamboo, so now I'll make the edit on Bamboo, but the question is if there is a chance to handle the case in which, for some reason, the .apk could be not generated. Can the situation in which Gradle is configured to generate .apk files for each build but for some reason they aren't generated exist? Can it be handled?

Comment: Besides this, if on Bamboo the Artifacts path where to find .apk is different from that where they physically are, can this problem be handled in some way through a script or do I necessarily need to fix this thing manually?

Comment: I don't know the answer for the second question. But it's bamboo's job to expect the apks and fail if they're not generated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [required artifact](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs/8.1.3/com/atlassian/bamboo/specs/api/builders/plan/artifact/Artifact.html#required--) to your plan. Specify the exact location where you expect the generated apk files. The Bamboo plan build will fail if it doesn't find them there.